# With Statement Proper VBA Syntax

Tags: excel, vba

Both of these code lines seem to work but are they both ok behind the scenes?

Dim Name as Range

With Sheet7

Set Name = .Cells(Selection.Row, Application.Match("A3", Rows(2), 0))

Set Name = .Cells(Selection.Row, Application.Match("A3", .Rows(2), 0))

End With

Do you have to put a period in front of "Rows" or not?  Again it seems both work fine for finding the correct value.

Comment: Yes you most certainly need a period in front of `Rows` if you want it to refer to `Sheet7`.

Comment: When all else fails, consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement).